# make image area map without using dreamweaver/firebug

Tags: html, firebug, dreamweaver, imagemap

Is their any way that one can make the image area map without using **Dreamweaver**?

Manually its difficult to play with the coordinates to design a perfect composition i think, well currently i am trying to map the areas with the help of **Firebug in Mozilla Firefox** or buy Dreamweaver itself but can work on it if your working with online FTP..

```
<img id="image" src="images/xyz.png" usemap="#image" border="0" alt="" />
    <map id="imagemap" name="image">
        <area shape="rect" coords="x,y,z,w" href="#" alt="" title="" />
        <area shape="rect" coords="x,y,z,w" href="#" alt="" title="" />
        <area shape="rect" coords="x,y,z,w" href="#" alt="" title="" />
    </map>
```

Is their any other time saver stuff or alternative to map the image areas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct me if I have misunderstood you, but you can try these services
for creating img maps:

http://www.image-maps.com/

http://www.maschek.hu/imagemap/

http://www.kolchose.org/simon/ajaximagemapcreator/

Comment: I'm glad you found the answer. You can mark the question as closed.